# Update multiple rows in cursor

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to work on this program step by step. Like in the code below I want to print old price and print new price after updating table inventory using cursor.

Using cursor to update many rows of data, create a procedure that accepts a number represent the percentage increase in price. The procedure will display the old price, new price, and update the database with the new price.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p5 
AS
CURSOR invent_cur IS
SELECT inv_price
FROM inventory;
v_inv_price inventory.inv_price%TYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN invent_cur;
LOOP
FETCH invent_cur INTO v_inv_price;
EXIT WHEN invent_cur%NOTFOUND;

IF (v_inv_price <= 0)
THEN
UPDATE inventory
set inv_price = inv_price*10;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_inv_price);
END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE invent_cur;
END;
/
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this around your update statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p5 (in_pc IN number)
AS
CURSOR invent_cur IS
SELECT inv_price
FROM inventory
WHERE inv_price > 0 
FOR UPDATE;
v_inv_price inventory.inv_price%TYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN invent_cur;
LOOP
FETCH invent_cur INTO v_inv_price;
EXIT WHEN invent_cur%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('before: '||v_inv_price);
v_inv_price := v_inv_price * in_pc ;

UPDATE inventory
set inv_price = v_inv_price
WHERE CURRENT OF invent_cur;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after: '||v_inv_price);

END LOOP;
```

In order to execute:

```
SET serveroutput ON
exec p5(10);
commit; -- to save the changes
```

Comment: hi,, i tried but it did nt wrkd,, can u please suggest any other alternative

Comment: @user10997164 please see revised answer

Comment: @user10997164 out of curiosity why IF (v_inv_price <= 0) ?

Comment: i replaced my update statement with urs. but still no values are showing as output. and when i am checking the output using select * from inventory it is showing same value updated for all the prices

Comment: IF (v_inv_price <= 0)

Comment: your code updates only negative values, that's why i am asking why the IF (v_inv_price <= 0). if your table has only positive values then nothing would have updated. Further more in order to see dbms_output you have to set serveroutput on before exec p5;

Comment: @user10997164 you got it the other way around it should be IF (v_inv_price > 0). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @user10997164 i updated the answer again. hope it works now

Comment: I'm wondering how many rows there are in `inventory`, and what the OP learns from the output.